# Where does min/max/average calculation take place?

Tags: ravendb

I have a data logging application. I record 10,000 temperatures every 30 seconds. I need to be able to calculate the min/max/average temperature of each of the 10,000 items over a hourly/daily/weekly basis. Can the min/max/Average calculation be performed on the server or does each document need to be downloaded to the client for the calculation to be performed?

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Either calculate or store a summary in the DB/ on the server. Keep the original data as well, if this is important.

Calculating a summary early & sending that to the client/ human level, is far more efficient than trucking around 10,000 samples that nobody usually wants to drill into.

A really good summary having average, min, max & standard deviation would be statistically comprehensive for almost all purposes.

When the client really wants, then you can bring down the big dataset (10k samples) and display it.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you want to calculate it on the server, but there are multiple approaches you might consider:

- You could store these in a specific documents that you manually update with each sample.  This could work, but you would be putting a lot of stress on a single document, and it could lead to concurrency issues.
- You can write a Map/Reduce index to calculate the totals.  Every time you write a new document, RavenDB will update your index with the new totals.  You can divide total value by total count to get an average, and you can easily use min and max functions.  Since you want to view these results by different time intervals, you'll need multiple indexes.

  I actually wrote a small demo program that does exactly that.  Instead of temperature, it's recording PSI values from simulated pressure gauges.  But the concepts are identical.  There are a few shortcuts in there that you can probably pick up on if you read the comments closely.

  Project Site: [Raven Sensors](https://github.com/mj1856/RavenSensors)

  I wrote this when the current version of RavenDB was 2.0.2261.  I haven't updated it in a while, but it should still work and be relevant.
- I haven't done much with it yet, but RavenDB 2.5 added a feature called [Dynamic Aggregation](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/dynamic-aggregation).  It is also exposed through the studio as [Dynamic Reporting](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/studio/dynamic-reporting).  Essentially, this does the aggregation at query time.  You may find it much easier to express the aggregations you are interested in, but it could be considerably slower than a map-reduce approach.  You may want to experiment.  The performance difference may come down to how many items are in the set being aggregated.